# router-link to path with params

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to go to a UserDetail path in my `vue` `app` using *vue-router*.

My routes are :

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/users', component: UserList },
  { path: '/users/:user_id', component: UserDetail },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]
```

And router link :

```
    <td><router-link :to = "{ path: 'users/:user_id', params: {user_id: user.id}} ">{{user.name}}</router-link></td>
```

But this is clearly not the correct syntax. I normally used named routes (see https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html for example) for this type of stuff but how could I use path?

#### edit #1

mousing over one of the links:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The solution is simple. Just do like [router-link docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html) says:

```
<td>
  <router-link :to="{ name:'users', params: { user_id: user.id }">
    {{user.name}}
  </router-link>
</td>
```

If you want to pass the parameters like this, you should use `name` instead of `path` inside the `:to`.